# Scala - simple tuple generation

Tags: scala

I am trying to generate N tuples, where the first element is the relative time from the (`start + i mins)` and the second is the content with the corresponding id appended at the end. My code looks a bit messy to me, I was hop[ing maybe somene could point out some operators/methods which might be more concise. Here's what I have so far:

```
1 to messageCount map (i => start.plusMinutes(i)) zip (1 to messageCount map (i => message + i))
```

Comment: I think this is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
for (i <- 1 to messageCount)
  yield (start.plusMinutes(i), message + 1)
```

IMHO you don't need the `zip` in this case, it even makes it look more complicated than it is.